# A question about how to make calculus after making a group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a Data Frame with categorical values where my input DataFrame is below:

df

```
 Age   Gender    Smoke
 18    Female    Yes 
 24    Female    No
 18    Female    Yes
 34    Male      Yes
 34    Male      No
```

I want to groupby my DataFrame based on columns "Age" and "Gender" where "Occurrence" column calculates the frequency of each selection and then, I want to create two other columns "Smoke Yes" that calculates number of smoking people based on the selection and "Smoke No" that calculates number of non smoking people

```
Age   Gender   Occurence   Smoke Yes     Smoke No
18    Woman     2            0.50             0.50
24    Woman     1            0                1
34    Man       2            0.5              0.5
```

In order to do that, I used the following code

```
#Group and sort
df1=df.groupby(['Age', 'Gender']).size().reset_index(name='Frequency').sort_values('Frequency', ascending=False)

#Delete index
df1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

However the df['Smoke'] column is disappeared so I can't continue my calculus. Does any one have an idea and what can I do to obtain like the output DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupby` and `value_counts` with `normalize=True` to return percentage share. then `unstack`. Also using a dictionary you can replace the `Gender` column to match the desired output.

```
d = {"Female":"Woman","Male":"Man"}

u = (df.groupby(['Age','Gender'])['Smoke'].value_counts(normalize=True)
       .unstack().fillna(0))

s = df.groupby("Age")['Gender'].value_counts()
u.columns = u.columns.name+"_"+u.columns

out=u.rename_axis(None,axis=1).assign(Occurance=s).reset_index().replace({"Gender":d})
```

---

```
print(out)

   Age Gender  Smoke_No  Smoke_Yes  Occurance
0   18  Woman       0.0        1.0          2
1   24  Woman       1.0        0.0          1
2   34    Man       0.5        0.5          2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However, is there an option in value_counts to obtain percentages. For example,In columns Smoke_No or Smoke_Yes, My values are 50, 100 instead of 0.50 or 1?

Comment: @Chloe, add `.mul(100)` after fillna. `(df.groupby(['Age','Gender'])['Smoke'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().fillna(0).mul(100))` this will multiply the results with 100

Comment: @Chloe if the solution worked, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it so as to close the Q&A.